# Что-то про html и css

Tags: html, css

Сразу говорю: я новичёк. Вопрос состоит таким образом: Я знаю, что стили css подключаются тегом link, и это один файл. Этот файл очень быстро забивается и становится гигантским. Так вот, добавляют ли веб программисты отдельные файлы со стилями к другим элементам сайта или так и пишут весь код в одном файле? Просто хочется узнать.

Comment: В CSS есть импорты, в SCSS есть импорты (вот у SCSS при компиляции попадет в один файл ну или несколько, в зависимости от структуры).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чаще всего пользуются различными сборщиками типа `Gulp`. С помощью него можно писать код в разных CSS, а он всё соберёт в один файл

К примеру, ты можешь писать стиль для шапки в файле `header.css`, а стиль для какого-то блока - в файле , `block.css` , но всё это будет собираться в один `style.css` и к html будет подключаться он один

Comment: Блин, спасибо, первый раз задаю тут вопрос и просто кайфую, как это круто. Приятно осознавать, что ты часть комьюнити разработчиков и есть кому помочь

Comment: @Nick  Если ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour